# How to implement query filtering using a Corda-Spring-Webserver?

Tags: java, spring, corda

I use Corda-Spring-Webserver. Tell me how I can implement request filtering to the controllers.

Comment: What kind of filtering are you talking about here?

Comment: about the mechanism that would allow to do user authentication and filter out non-authenticated

Answer (score 1):

There is no Corda-Spring-webserver. You either use the Corda-Webserver which uses Jetty internally or you use any Web server along with Spring it can be tomcat or undertow or jetty.

For request filtering with Corda-Webserver(uses Jersey Internally) you'll have to go the jersey way using ContainerRequestFilter. Implement this filter to any of your class and then filter the request you want as per your need.

If using spring you can use interceptors to filter your requests.